# SQL Select When Something IS NOT IN a Joined Table

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, join, left-join, outer-join

Ok.  I have some data in one table, that references on multiple occasions some data in another table.

Table1 - main client table
Table2 - user defined fields

Say I have a query that shows a client id from Table1 and all attached / used "used defined fields" from Table2

```
SELECT t1.Id, t2.udf
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Index
WHERE t1.EndDate IS NULL AND
      t1.Id = '1234.9876' AND
```

I would get the following for a result...

```
ID            UDF
1234.9876     100
1234.9876     110
1234.9876     118
1234.9876     124
1234.9876     198
1234.9876     256
```

Now, say I wanted to query this same thing, and get ONLY the ID of the Client, but ONLY IF a value for t2.udf equaling '194' did not exist.  So, I would simply get

```
ID           
1234.9876
```

...as a result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make the join a LEFT join and filer where t2.Index is null

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Index
AND t2.UDF = 194   -- has to be before where clause
WHERE t2.Index IS NULL
AND t1.EndDate IS NULL 
AND t1.Id = '1234.9876'  -- not sure if you want this part
```

Another way by using NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM Table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM  Table2 t2 WHERE t1.Id = t2.INDEX
                AND t2.UDF = 194)
AND t1.EndDate IS NULL 
AND t1.Id = '1234.9876'
```

See also [JOINS](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/sql-advent-2011-day-15)

Comment: +1 [`NOT EXISTS` is by far the best](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join) in almost all cases.

Comment: @AaronBertrand If Table2 has a FK relationship to Table1 on the join column and the column is part of a composite PK on Table2 is there a hit to left join?

Comment: This was EXACTLY what I needed.  I've used LEFT JOIN's before, but never in that manner.  You learn something new every day, huh?  Thank you VERY VERY much.  You're a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You can add AND t2.udf not in (select udf from table2 where udf <> '194'). 
But @SQLMenace solution is better

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.Id 
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Index
WHERE t2.UDF NOT IN (194)
AND t2.Index IS NULL
```

Select DISTINCT gives you unique entries that satisfy the other conditions, and the first where clause

```
  t2.UDF NOT IN (194)
```

Normall would return all the rows for the t1 where the t2.UDF is not 194, but it is limited by the Select Distinct to give you only distinct id's

Answer (score -1):

Try the following:

```
SELECT t1.Id
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Index
WHERE t1.EndDate IS NULL AND
      t1.Id = '1234.9876' AND
      t2.udf <> '194'
```